# Rewrite rules for localhost AND live environment

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to add rewriterules that works in local environment (localhost) and on my liveserver.

Why?

I don't want to change rules when I test my project locally and upload it to the liveserver.

1. **Adding Rules**

   Here an example

   ```
   (ANY-URL)index.php?page=somepage
   ```

   change to

   ```
   (ANY-URL)/somepage
   ```

   So I used a rewritemod generator and pasted this into it:

   ```
   index.php?page=somepage
   ```

   The rewriterule I got, looks like this: (of course my .htacces starts with RewriteEngine On)

   ```
   RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?page=$1 [L]
   ```

   When I try to get to `(http:) 
   //localhost/myproject/development/index.php?page=login` it sends me to the root directory of my local development envirment. But the URL in the adressline doesn't change.
2. **Testing**

   Of course I tried some other Rules by pasting the whole URL into the generator just to test if the rewrite thing works. 
   Also here the URL doesn't change to short-url but the server cant find stylesheets and javascripts anymore. I got redirected to the index.php
3. **Possible solutions?**

   - Maybe it has something todo with that "RewriteBase"?
   - Do i have to set a basepath?

My .htacces is located here:

```
//localhost/myproject/development/.htaccess
```

Later I also want to change paths that look like this:

```
(ANY-URL)index.php?page=somepage&second=hello&third=world&fourth=cool
```

Also here a I'm looking for a solution that works on both environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the htaccess is located inside a sub-directory, use `RewriteBase`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myproject/development/
```

Once that is done, you use the `base` element in your php/html files. This will resolve the addresses for the scripts/stylesheets in your pages.

```
<base href="/myproject/development/" />
```

Now, the rewrites in htaccess would be:

```
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php)[^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! So I use multiple .htacces files(in different subfolders)?

Comment: @Fdev If you wish. You should also go through: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20563772/1190388

Comment: Thanks, it works so far. Seems like it works only into one direction (from long to short URL) I think I need another rewriterule to do the same job from short to long URL. PS: I don't need the base-element in HTML - just RewriteBase in .htaccess-file :)

Comment: What do I have toDo with rewritebase when I upload the project to http://www.[myproject].com? Remove it?

Comment: @Fdev Yes! Or, you can change it to `RewriteBase /`

Comment: I followed your link and it is very helpful - I will have to read it a few more times.

Here is another try to rewrite another url:

`//localhost/myproject/development/index.php?page=somepage&keyword=test&zip=12345&range=50`

to

`//localhost/myproject/development/somepage/test/53229/50`

My solution looks like this:

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1&keyword=$2&zip=$3&range=$4

I also used a generator that gave me the same solution but this didn't work here.

Maybe I have to count in your given rule and I have to rewrite this URL then?