# htaccess for local testing and live server

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp, localhost

I'm close, to my final solution I think.
The *.htaccess* looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myproject/development/
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php)[^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php)[^/]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&keyword=$2&zip=$3&range=$4 [L,R]
```

I don't need the RewriteBase for the 1st rule(was a little surprised about that) but I need it if I add the 2nd rule and open this URL:

```
//localhost/myproject/development/somepage/test/13245/50
```

Otherwise the page will be opened but of course without the stylesheets and javaScripts can be found then.

**1.) Target:** I want to use the 2nd rewriteRule without changing or adding a rewriteBase. What do I need to change in the *.htaccess* so I can keep testing my project without a rewriteBase.

**Why:** As I asked before I want to test my project locally and on the live-server without changing too much on the project configuration.

**2.) The [R] Flag** If I request

```
//localhost/myproject/development/somepage/test/53229/2000
```

Of course in the adressline then we have this URL

```
//localhost/myproject/development/index.php?page=somepage&keyword=test&zip=12345&range=2000
```

To avoid this behaviour I simply should remove the R-Flag. But then the CSS and JS can't be found anymore. Also Here I'm looking for a solution without rewritebase, basepath, virtual host, etc. if possible.

Here is where I started:
[Rewrite rules for localhost AND live envoirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045018/rewrite-rules-for-localhost-and-live-envoirement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks, you don't want the `R` flag on the 2nd `RewriteRule`. That defeats the object of your "pretty" URLs.

> But then the CSS and JS can't be found anymore.

Because you are using relative paths to your CSS and JS files. Either change your paths to root-relative (starting with a slash), or use the `base` element in the `head` section of your pages, to indicate the URL that all relative URLs are relative to:

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/page.html">
```

More Information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

---

> I don't need the RewriteBase for the 1st rule(was a little surprised about that)

You don't need the `RewriteBase` for the 1st rule (an *internal rewrite*) because the directory-prefix (the filesystem path that lead to this .htaccess file) is automatically added back on relative path substitutions.

However, for *external redirects* (ie. `R` flag), the directory-prefix does not make sense, so you either need to specify a root-relative (starting with a slash) or absolute URL. Or specify the appropriate `RewriteBase` directive, which overrides what URL-path will be added for relative substitutions (that's all it does).